# No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: class boost::shared_ptr<class MyCallback>

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I want to embed python in c++ with Boost.Python.

Environment:

1. VC++2019 x64 project
2. Anaconda env 3.6 64bit

Python code in `mypackage/mymodule.py`:

```
class Order:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class MyCallback:
    def on_order(self, order):
        pass


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name, id, callback):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.callback = callback

    def send_order(self, name):
        order = Order(name)
        self.callback.on_order(order)
```

C++ code:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::python;
using namespace boost::python::api;


class MyCallback {
public:
    void on_order(boost::python::object order) {
    }
};


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mylib)
{
    boost::python::class_<MyCallback>("MyCallback")
        .def("on_order", &MyCallback::on_order)
    ;

    boost::python::register_ptr_to_python<boost::shared_ptr<MyCallback>>();
} 


int main() {
    try {
        Py_SetPythonHome(const_cast<wchar_t*>(L"C:/Users/xxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/py36_64"));
        Py_Initialize();

        auto mymodule = boost::python::import("mypackage.mymodule");
        auto my_class = mymodule.attr("MyClass");
        try {
            auto myCallback = boost::make_shared<MyCallback>();
            auto obj = my_class("John", 123, myCallback);
            obj.attr("send_order")("product1");
        }
        catch (...) {
            PyObject *ptype, *pvalue, *ptraceback;
            PyErr_Fetch(&ptype, &pvalue, &ptraceback);
            std::wstring strErrorMessage = boost::python::extract<std::wstring>(pvalue);
        }

        Py_Finalize();
    }
    catch (...) {
            PyObject *ptype, *pvalue, *ptraceback;
            PyErr_Fetch(&ptype, &pvalue, &ptraceback);
            std::wstring strErrorMessage = boost::python::extract<std::wstring>(pvalue);
    }
}
```

I also tried:

```
auto obj = my_class("John", 123, boost::python::ptr(myCallback.get()));
```

The `strErrorMessage` will be:

> No Python class registered for C++ class class MyCallback

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

After compare with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9089645/1633272), I think a statement is missing before using `MyCallback`:

```
PyInit_mylib();
```

This is the Python 3 version. It is defined by the marcro `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mylib)`.

It should be `initmylib();` in Python 2.

See more here: [HowTo](https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/HowTo)