# getting a reference to self when using boost::python

Tags: boost-python

I am trying to port a Python class to C++ using boost::python with the hope of speeding up the execution of a Python application (the class I am porting to C++ is responsible for ~30% of the applications execution time).

The init of the original Python class looks like:

```
class PyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, child):
        child.set_parent(self)
        ...
```

How do I replicate this in a C++ constructor?

if I have a C++ class:

```
class CClass
{
    // to get input args that match the Python class I need
    CClass(boost::python::object &child)
    {
         // but how do I get the boost::python::object self
         // as I only have *this in C++ ?
         CClass& c = boost::python::extract<CClass&>(child);
         c.set_parent(self);
    }

    ...
}
```

Thanks,  Mark

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `this` pointer via `boost::python::ptr(this)`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5056462/233201).